# Pandas and Numpy Fancy Indexing

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am having a hard time with the following. I have a pandas `N x D` dataframe called `p` with some missing (`NAN`) values. I have another corresponding array indexed by `D x K x T`. I want to make a map of every panda's entry `n,d` in the data frame to `a[d][k][p[n,d]]` for all possible k resulting in `N x D x K` matrix. Can I have some help as to how to do this most efficiently with the Pandas and Numpy library?

I actually then take the `N x D` part of the final matrix and take the product along the columns leaving an `N x K` matrix. The final output can be (slowly) reproduced by the following:

```
    def generate_entry(i, j):
        result = np.prod([alpha[s][j][int(p.loc[i][s])] for s in range(num_features) if not isNaN(p.loc[i][s]) ])
        return result

    vgenerate_entry = np.vectorize(generate_entry)
    result = np.fromfunction(vgenerate_entry, shape=(len(p), k), dtype=int)
```

I think some use of `pandas.get_dummies` would be helpful for matrix multiplication but I can't quite figure that out.

The following is much faster:

```
    r = None
    for i in range(num_features):
        rel_data = pd.get_dummies(data.ix[:,i])
        rel_probs = alpha[i].T
        prod = rel_data.dot(rel_probs)
        prod[prod == 0] = 1
        if r is None:
            r = prod
        else:
            r = r.multiply(prod)

    r = r.as_matrix()
    r = r * pi
    posteriers = r / np.sum(r, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
```

Comment: Yes, it is just quite slow.

Comment: Could you share it? How are you planning to avoid the NaNs in `p`/ What must be the output corresponding to those NaNs?

Comment: the map should go to nan if p[n,d] is nan

Comment: Got it. Share the loopy code?

Comment: shared and altered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach to index into the NumPy array `a` with the pandas dataframe `p` that has `NaNs`, which are to be avoided and we are filling some value `fillval` in those places -

```
def fancy_indexing_avoid_NaNs(p, a, fillval = 1):
    # Extract values from p and get NaN mask
    pv = p.values
    mask = np.isnan(pv)

    # Get int version, replacing NaNs with some number, say 0
    p_idx = np.where(mask, 0, pv).astype(int)

    # FANCY-INDEX into array 'a' with those indices fron p
    a_indexed_vals = a[np.arange(D), np.arange(K)[:,None,None],p_idx]

    # FANCY-INDEX once more to replace the values set by NaNs as 1s, so
    # that in the prod-reduction later on they would have no effect
    a_indexed_vals[np.arange(K)[:,None,None],mask] = fillval
    return a_indexed_vals
```

That `fillval` would be application dependent. In this case, we are using `prod`, so a `fillval=1` makes sense, which won't affect the results.

Original approach posted by OP -

```
def generate_entry(i, j):
    result = np.prod([a[s][j][int(p.loc[i][s])] for s in range(D) \
                                   if not np.isnan(p.loc[i][s]) ])
    return result

vgenerate_entry = np.vectorize(generate_entry)
```

Sample run -

```
In [154]: N,D,K,T = 3,4,5,6
     ...: a = np.random.randint(0,5,(D,K,T))
     ...: 
     ...: p = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,T,(N,D)).astype(float))
     ...: p.iloc[2,3] = np.nan
     ...: p.iloc[1,2] = np.nan
     ...: 

In [155]: result = np.fromfunction(vgenerate_entry, shape=(len(p), K), dtype=int)

In [156]: a_indexed_vals = fancy_indexing_avoid_NaNs(p, a)

In [157]: out = a_indexed_vals.prod(2).T

In [158]: np.allclose(out, result)
Out[158]: True
```